# div containing jquery progress bar inside <ul> list

Tags: jquery, css, list, html

I am trying to add a jquery progress bar inside a ul li tag.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="test">test</a>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I use display: block for the anchor tag and I tried the same for the div tag but with no luck. The div elements displays below the anchor tag. I would like the progress bar to be on the same line as the anchor tag.

Laurent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

```
#progressbar { display: inline; }
```

will put it on the same line. I don't know if it has to be display: block or not.

Alternatively, with:

```
<ul>
  <li class="load">
    <a href="test">test</a>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try:

```
li.load { overflow: hidden; }
li.load a, li.load div { float: left; }
```

although you *might* need to enclose the items in a div:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="load">
      <a href="test">test</a>
      <div id="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then use:

```
div.load { overflow: hidden; }
div.load a, div.load div { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display them both inline or float them both left, that will get them on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

By "the tag" do you mean the `a` tag? If so, you can try giving the `div` a style of `display: inline-block`. The progressbar plugin might or might not work with that, but if it works, the progress bar should get laid out inline with the `a`, which is an inline child of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the entire progress bar being a link, you can do the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="test">
      <div id="progressbar">test</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

... and the CSS:

```
div {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

---

Or if you need to keep the HTML the way it is try some CSS like this:

```
li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;     /* Position as needed */
  left: 2px;
}

li div {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;  /* height and width should be your desired size */
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Re-read the question, this isn't what you're trying to do, try the float left thing cletus suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.load a
        {
            display: block;
        }
        li.load a, li.load div
        {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="load"><a href="test">test</a>
                <div id="progressbar">

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```